# How can I get all column values in dataframe-js as array?

Tags: dataframe-js

I use [dataframe-js](https://gmousse.gitbooks.io/dataframe-js/#dataframe-js) to create a `dataframe` like this:

```js
const df = new DataFrame({
    column1: [3, 6, 8], // <------ A column
    column2: [3, 4, 5, 6],
}, ['column1', 'column2']);
```

How can I access / print an array containing all `column1` values (in this case: `[3, 6, 8]`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out that this should do the job:

```js
const column1 = df.toArray('column1')
```

And to calculate a sum of all column1 values:

```js
var sum = df.reduce((p, n) => n.get('column1') + p, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you mentioned, the following code should work.

```
const column1Array = df.select("column1").toArray();;
```

Comment: Thanks but `select` returns a `dataframe` so probably a little too expensive, yet giving you vote-up for helping